# Access parent element

Tags: less

I have the following html and less

```
<div class="status">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p class="status-1">Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.status {
    div {
        div {
            p {
                color: red;

                .status-1 {
                    color: blue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where there is a `<p>` element nested in a couple of divs. Now I'm looking to add the `status-1` class to the base div, to create a html structure like this:

```
<div class="status status-1">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But now I can't figure out how to access the `.status` element from inside the `p` element in less. I could just type

```
.status {
    &.status-1 {
        div {
            div {
                p {
                    color: blue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But since there are multiple `.status` classes (e.g. `status-0`, `status-1`, `status-2`) that would suck to copy paste that same bit of code. Is there any way in less I would be able to access the parent `.status` element? I was hoping for something like

```
.status {
    div {
        div {
            p {
                color: red;

                ->parent(.status.status-1) {
                    color: blue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Parent Selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature), e.g.:

```
.status {
     p {
        color: red;
        .status-1& {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that though the generated selector is `.status-1.status`, it still matches both `class="status status-1"` and `class="status-1 status"` elements.